# Can't see modification in frontend

Tags: cache, static-block

i'm new here and started using Magento a couple of days ago for study. Now i am at the frontend part and i want to make some changes.

Magento store is version 1.8.1.0 and i installed it on my localhost using xampp.

What i'm trying to do is to see my modifications to a Static Block or a Page in frontend. For example if i change the text for a page, save the content, go in frontend and refresh the page nothing happens, no modification is made.

As i assume, is a problem with Cache Management or Index Management but i don't know how to set them up.

Please help me resolve this issue, what changes do i have to make in order to work or what steps do i have to follow?

Thanks, George

Answer (score 0):

You need disable Cache to see the changes in: System-> Cache Management (Select all) all inactive cache.

If you need configure a Development enviroment you can follow this link: http://foggyline.net/magento/setting-up-magento-development-environment/

Thus you can test everything showing up the errors, the changes, etc